# ifstream does not return the correct int value

Tags: c++, file-io, ifstream

I want to make a factory class which creates and loads objects in from a file;
however when I try to read in a `int` from the file it appears to return a incorrect number.

```
std::ifstream input;
input.open("input.txt");
if (!input.is_open()){
    exit(-1);

}

int number;

input >> number;
cout << number;

input.close();
```

When I enter a number in the `input.txt` file it shows: `-858993460`.
Changing the number doesn’t make a difference and when I use `cin` instead of `ifstream` it works like it should. I'm probably just missing something really stupid, but I can't figure it out.

Edit: Using `getLine()` works like it should. I guess there is a problem using >>.

Comment: [Why are you not checking the input operation?](http://kayari.org/cxx/yunocheckio.html) What makes you think it read _any_ value, right or wrong, if you don't check it?

Comment: -858993460 is the decimal value of 0xCCCCCCCC, which is what you get for unassigned variables. That is because your `number` variable was not filled with a value read from the file.

Comment: What does _"when i enter a number in the input.txt file"_ mean? Are you trying to edit the input.txt file while the program is reading from it? What does the file contain when the program starts running?

Comment: Hunch: the file you're editing isn't the same file as the one your program is opening.

Comment: [When and why will an OS initialise memory to 0xCD, 0xDD, etc. on malloc/free/new/delete?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/370195/995714)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another solution to open a file a read it line by line:

```
string line;
ifstream myfile("input.txt");
if (myfile.is_open())
{
  while ( getline (myfile,line) )
  {
    cout << line << '\n'; // Use this to verify that the number is outputed
    // Here you can transform your line into an int:
    // number = std::stoi(line);
  }
  // myfile.close(); Use this if you want to handle the errors
}

else cout << "Unable to open file";
```

If you don't want to read line by line, just remove the `while`

```
...
getline(myfile,line);
number = std::stoi(line);
...
```

**Read multiple numbers in one line**

Image that your input file is like this:

> 1, 2.3, 123, 11
>
> 1, 2
>
> 0.9, 90

Then, you can use this piece of code to read all the numbers:

```
string line;
ifstream myfile("input.txt");
string delimiter = ", ";

if (myfile.is_open())
{
  while ( getline (myfile,line) )
  {
    cout << "Reading a new line: " << endl;
    size_t pos = 0;
    string token;
    while ((pos = line.find(delimiter)) != string::npos) {
      token = line.substr(0, pos);
      cout << token << endl; // Instead of cout, you can transform it into an int
      line.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
    }
  }
}
else cout << "Unable to open file";
```

The output will be:

```
Reading a new line: 
1
2.3
123
11
Reading a new line:
1
2
Reading a new line:
0.9
90
```

**New solution that may work =)**

I didn't test this, but it works apparently:

```
std::ifstream input;
double val1, val2, val3;
input.open ("input.txt", std::ifstream::in);
if (input >> val1 >> val2 >> val3) {
  cout << val1 << ", " << val2 << ", " << val3 << endl;
}
else
{
  std::cerr << "Failed to read values from the file!\n";
  throw std::runtime_error("Invalid input file");
}
```

To check the IO, see http://kayari.org/cxx/yunocheckio.html

Comment: What's the point of `myfile.close()`? Don't you trust the destructor?

Comment: I have the habit of always closing the streams even if they have a destructor.. I don't know if it's a good or a bad habit.. =) But it doesn't change anything normally..

Comment: @Smeiliz: see [my question on codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/540/implementation-using-fstream-failed-evaluation)

Comment: The point is that i want multiple values read and assigned, so i can use:
    input >> x >> y >> health;
or something like that

Comment: @Jasper: I may have found something easier to use.. Apparently, you were just missing `std::infstream::in` when opening the file..

Comment: @Smeiliz, no, `ifstream` always opens for input by default. And your new solution is still not [checking the input works](http://kayari.org/cxx/yunocheckio.html).

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Is it better like this?? I edited it..
Correct me if I'm wrong, but the first solution is better right?? It's more safe, no??